# Smooth scrolling from one page to another using GSAP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, gsap

I am using Greensock animation for smooth scroll clicking on the menu. I have three pages which are `menu.php, index.php, terms.php`.

Now I am on `index.php` page and there is no issue with scrolling if I 
 clicking on the menu then it's targeting the right id. No issue on the index page.

Now I am on `terms.php` page from there If I click on the about menu then it's not redirecting on the id.
I am getting the URL like `http://localhost/test-menu/terms.php#contact`

Would you help me out in this?

In the `menu.php` page, I added my menu code which is

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In the `index.php`, I added the code which is

```
<?php include('menu.php'); ?>
<section id="about">
<h2>About</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</section>
<section id="services">
    <h2>Service</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>

<section id="contact">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.0/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
```

In the `terms.php`, I added the code

```
<?php include('menu.php'); ?>
    <section>
        <h2>terms</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    </section>
```

GSAP smooth scroll script

```
/** Smooth Scrolling Functionality **/
$(document).ready(function() {
// Init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
// Change behavior of controller
// to animate scroll instead of jump
controller.scrollTo(function(target) {
    TweenMax.to(window, 2, {
        scrollTo : {
        y : target-65, // scroll position of the target along y axis
        autoKill : true, // allows user to kill scroll action smoothly
        },
        ease : Cubic.easeInOut
    });
    });
//  Bind scroll to anchor links
$(document).on("click", "a[href^=#]", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    if($(id).length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // trigger scroll
        controller.scrollTo(id);
        // If supported by the browser we can also update the URL
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            history.pushState("", document.title, id);
        }
    };
});
});
```

**Css**

```
ul{margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style: none;}
ul li{display: inline-block;margin: 10px;}
section{min-height: 500px;}
```

Comment: Have you tried `index.php#contact` in you `menu.php` instead of just the anchor?

Comment: @t3__rry, Thanks for the reply, If I tried index.php#contact then smooth scrolling will not work. I tried that before. It's directly jumping on the id

Comment: Ok sure but you need to navigate back to your `index.php`
What if you grab the ìd` from the actual URL: `const hash = new URL(window.location).hash` instead of the `href` attribute? My other concern is that your script might not be ready after the page has rendered so it would be inefficient and scroll to the anchor

Comment: @t3__rry, That's right, I have to navigate on the index.php page but how to do this? I tried index.php#contact but it's jumping on the div. any other solution?

Comment: @t3__rry, Any more help in this?

Comment: Have you tried refactoring your `onClick` and grabbing the URL's hash as I suggested above instead of getting the `href` attribute from the `a` element ?

Comment: @t3__rry, I am so sorry, I haven't tried because I don't know how to do that. Can you help me out with the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172692/discussion-between-t3-rry-and-user9437856).

Comment: @t3__rry, Any more help in this?

Comment: Could you create a plunker?

Comment: @t3__rry, I send you the code on chat discussion